# In Magento 2, how to disable a menu for particular admin user

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

In Magento 2, how to disable a menu for particular admin  user

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a particular User Role by going to `System/User Roles` and create a User Role by selecting menus to be shown for particular Admin user. Then go to `System/All Users` and select the admin user-if created already-and assign him that role you just created.

Comment: I already create a user role for the admin. I just want to know how to enable an admin  menu  for  only the "Administrator" user

Comment: For that you need to create another User Role that would apply to other users except admin and disable that menu for those users that you just want to enable for "Administrator"

Comment: I already created more than 4 sub-admin with different user role instead of  "Administrator". I m just asking about I don't know how to disable an admin menu

Answer (score 0):

From the system/User Roles , you can add user role with custom resources(like attached screenshot) and allocate that role to particular user.

[image]